# SQL Server XQuery error: A node or set of nodes is required for number()

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, sql-server-2012, xquery

I have the following query in SQL Server 2012:

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml =
'<Root>
    <Value>false</Value>
</Root>'

SELECT
    node.value('concat(substring("T", 1, number((./Value/text())[1] = "true")), substring("F", 1, number(not((./Value/text())[1] = "true"))))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [ValueTF]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Root') AS input(node)
```

This is using the method of deriving a ternary-style operation as described here: [How to create an if-then-else expression (aka ternary operator) in an XPath 1.0 expression?](http://technology.amis.nl/2014/06/14/how-to-create-an-if-then-else-expression-aka-ternary-operator-in-an-xpath-1-0-expression/)

I would expect this query to return `F` for `ValueTF`, but instead it gives the following error message:

> Msg 2374, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   XQuery [value()]: A node or set of nodes is required for number()

Even the simplified XPath `number((./Value/text())[1] = "true")` returns the same error. A Google search for "A node or set of nodes is required for number()" returns no results. The query successfully executes and returns `F` as expected when executed elsewhere, such as in [this online XPath tester](http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php).

The following query does return `false` for `Value` as expected, so I know that at least that part of the query is working correctly:

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml =
'<Root>
    <Value>false</Value>
</Root>'

SELECT
    node.value('(./Value/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Value]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Root') AS input(node)
```

The [W3 spec for the number function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-number) seems to indicate that `xs:anyAtomicType` can be passed as an argument to `number`, which includes `xs:boolean`. So, is there an error in my code or is this a difference in SQL Server's XQuery implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you, I don't know why SQL Server's implementation of `number()` won't take a boolean argument... nor even a string, apparently! That's pretty strange.

Nevertheless, if they support XQuery, they should by definition support XPath 2.0, which means that you don't need to use this ugly `concat()` workaround to simulate the ternary conditional operator: XPath 2.0 has the real thing!

So instead of

```
'concat(substring("T", 1, number((./Value/text())[1] = "true")),
       substring("F", 1, number(not((./Value/text())[1] = "true"))))'
```

you should be able to say

```
'if ((./Value/text())[1] = "true") then "T" else "F"'
```

I haven't tested that in SQL Server 2012, but it is part of XQuery, and it's documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190171(v=sql.110).aspx), so it's worth a try.

Comment: This does work in SQL Server 2012, thanks! I'm not sure why I was under the impression that I was restricted to XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research I came across the following page describing the implementation details of `number()` in SQL Server 2012: [number Function (XQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191139(v=sql.110).aspx). From that page under the Implementation Limitations section:

> The number() function only accepts nodes. It does not accept atomic values.

So, it seems that the issue is that the SQL Server implementation of `number()` will not take a boolean argument, though it's not clear to me why it was limited in that way.